# How to avoid temporary copies when using emplace to add to a std::map?

Tags: c++11, stl, containers, emplace

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct FooStruct 
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    map<int, FooStruct> fooMap;
    fooMap.emplace<int, FooStruct>(0, {1, 2});
    return 0;
}
```

In terms of preventing temporary copies, is the above a correct usage of emplace? Is the above form better than

```
fooMap.emplace(make_pair<int, FooStruct>(0, {1, 2}));
```

Or are these forms equivalent and both of them avoid creating a temporary copy of `FooStruct`?

Comment: Difference is `make_pair` uses move constructor semantics of `pair`, while other way you  call template's constructor.

Comment: What about `fooMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(0), std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2));` ?

Comment: @max66: Are you saying your form is better than the two mentioned above? if so, can you please explain why it is the case?

Comment: No; I only show you another way to do the same thing; if I'm not wrong, is (roughly) the same of the first form but without the need of explicit the template types (that can be nice in some circumstances).

Comment: @max66: +1 for eliminating the need to specify template types.

Answer (score 1):

If you define "correctness" as brevity, you may want to use `std::map::insert` instead of `std::map::emplace` like this:

```
fooMap.insert({0, {1, 2}});
```

With `emplace` you will have to either specify types explicitly like in your example or define a constructor in `FooStruct` explicitly in the case suggested by @max66:

```
fooMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(0),
    std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2));
```

(which also lacks brevity).

`fooMap.insert({0, {1, 2}});` should not be different from

```
fooMap.emplace(make_pair<int, FooStruct>(0, {1, 2}));
```

in terms of amount of objects created as it also uses move-constructor of `std::pair` as @Swift pointed out.

If "correct" means "compilable and works as expected on runtime", then both your examples are correct.

Comment: Okay, thanks. What I was really after was a single instance of FooStruct that gets constructed directly in the memory of the the map. `fooMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(0), std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2));` accomplishes just that. The other forms, concise or not, involve creation of a temporary FooStruct instance, which is something I want to avoid.

Comment: Could you please update your question to reflect that you were looking for minimal amount of objects constructed? Also, this form of `emplace` may produce little or no runtime performance benefits as compilers could optimise away all the difference and you may need to compare assembly.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Of the three forms discussed in this thread, the one that avoids unnecessary copies is the form proposed by @max66. The following code and its output captures these three forms in action

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct FooStruct 
{
    FooStruct() 
    { 
        cout << "FooStruct Default Constructor" << endl; 
    }
    FooStruct(const FooStruct& other) 
    {
        this->a = other.a;
        this->b = other.b;
        cout << "FooStruct Copy Constructor" << endl;
    }
    FooStruct(int a, int b)
    {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
        cout << "FooStruct Parametrized Constructor" << endl;
    }
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Output:

```
foo.emplace<int, FooStruct>(0, {1, 2})
FooStruct Parametrized Constructor
FooStruct Copy Constructor
fooMap.emplace(make_pair<int, FooStruct>(1, { 2, 3 }))
FooStruct Parametrized Constructor
FooStruct Copy Constructor
FooStruct Copy Constructor
fooMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(2), std::forward_as_tuple(2, 4))
FooStruct Parametrized Constructor
```

============

ORIGINAL (WRONG)

I was little lazy and didn't try to dig deeper before posting the question. I now see that all these three forms (third form comes from @max66's comment) are equivalent in that all three of them avoid the creation of a temporary copy of `FooStruct`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct FooStruct 
{
    FooStruct() { cout << "FooStruct Default Constructor" << endl; }
    FooStruct(int a, int b) { this->a = a; this->b = b; cout << "FooStruct Parametrized Constructor" << endl; }
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    map<int, FooStruct> fooMap;
    fooMap.emplace<int, FooStruct>(0, {1, 2});
    fooMap.emplace(make_pair<int, FooStruct>(1, { 2, 3 }));
    fooMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(2), std::forward_as_tuple(2, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

The above code (built with Visual C++ 2015) produces the following output:

```
FooStruct Parametrized Constructor
FooStruct Parametrized Constructor
FooStruct Parametrized Constructor
```

PS: I did verify that each line in the above output corresponds to a single emplace call above

Comment: I'm not agree about the fact that " that all these three forms [...] are equivalent in that all three of them avoid the creation of a temporary copy of FooStruct". This is true for the first and the third form; in the second form case, as far I know, there is the creation of a temporary copy of the pair `int`/`FooStruct` that is used to construct the pair in the map with the copy constructor (move constructor, starting from C++11).

Comment: @max66: You're correct. I forgot about the copy constructor and obviously reached the wrong conclusion. So, now we know your form that involves forward_as_tuple is the best solution. I will edit my answer to reflect this finding.